# Создание кнопки на сайте

Tags: javascript

Я на своем сайте вставил видео уроки, но так как уроков много, я их с помощью `css` (display:none;) спрятал. Идея такова: когда нажимаешь на кнопку `display:none;` должен меняться на `display:block;`. Мне это удалось: в див кнопки я добавил код

```
onClick=document.getElementById('p10').style.display='block'
```

Но вот как сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на ту же кнопку `display:block` менялся опять на `display:none`, то есть прятал опять плеер я не знаю.

В качестве временной меры я сделал, чтобы плеер прятался при наведении мышки на кнопку без нажатия, но это не удобно, так как случайное наведение прячет ролик. Надо, чтобы он прятался при повторном клике.

Чтобы было более понятно суть вопроса, вот ссылка на страницу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может как-то так?

```
onClick="var elem = document.getElementById('p10'); elem.style.display=((elem.style.display=='block')?'none':'block');"
```

Comment: Большое спасибо ваш вариант оказался самым коротким и удобным, и рабочим к тому же, вернее сказать не совсем рабочим, небольшая ошибка в синтаксисе, последние ковычки лишние, с ними не работает у меня работает вот такой вариант: 
onClick="var elem = document.getElementById('p10'); elem.style.display=((elem.style.display=='block')?'none':'block')";

Comment: Да, опечатка, спасибо :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Правильные show/hide/toggle](http://javascript.ru/ui/show-hide-toggle)

Comment: правильный show/hide/toggle:

    $('selector').show().hide().toggle()

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, которое пришло сходу на ум:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function buttonStatus() {
            if(document.getElementById('p10').style.display == 'none') {
                document.getElementById('p10').style.display='block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('p10').style.display='none';
            }
        }
    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="buttonStatus()" />

    <div id="p10">текст</div>
```

Вот более упрощенное:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function buttonStatus() {
        var elm = document.getElementById('p10').style;

         elm.display == 'none' ? elm.display ='block' : elm.display='none';
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click me" onClick="buttonStatus()" />

<div id="p10">текст</div>
```